# How to query SQL database from php on which user didn't send in his hour report for the last 30 days

Tags: php, sql, array-difference

I have an hoursheet import form where users submit the hours they worked per day. This data is send to a table called hours.

This table contains the columns:

> user, day, hours, begintime, endtime

I want to send every employee an email when they didn't send in their worked hours per day.

What I've tried so far: create an array with the active users. I created an array from an sql query in php with all the hoursheets per user from 'yesterday'.

With array_diff_assoc I have the users which didn't send in their hoursheet for 'yesterday'.

So no problem here. But I'm looking for a more clean solution that can do it for several days in the past. Let's say the last month. Does anybody have a good suggestion to push me in the right direction?

Database is sql
Programming language php

Don't get me wrong, I don't need tons of code. I'm not lazy I want to try to look for this myself. I just need a push in the right direction.

Real-life example:

Table structure:
**Hourimport table**     <----one to many <---- **User table**
|
one to many
|
**Hourimport detail**

Hourimport contains the dayreports unique record number, user, date, status, mail

Hourimport detail contains the details records of the dayreport. Multiple detail records per day.. For example one travel hour from 8 to 9 and working hours from 9 to 5. Breaks and miles driven. *not needed for this example because all the data I need is in the hourimport table.

users contains id, name, mail etc

```
echo '<br>STEP 1: <br>Connected successfully <br><br>';
$yesterdayT = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")-1, date("Y")));
$yesterday = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($gisterenT));
$yesterday = "'$gisteren'";


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$result = mysql_query("select id as employee from users inner join user_group on users.id=user_group.user_id where group_id=10 or group_id=11");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$rows = array();
while($rows[]=mysql_fetch_array($result));

echo "<br>A <--<pre>";
print_r ($rows);
echo "</pre><br><br>";
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$result1 = mysql_query("select employee from hourimport INNER JOIN hourimport_detail ON hourimport.id=hourimport_detail.parent_id WHERE hourimport.date =$yesterday");
if (!$result1) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$rows1 = array();
while($rows1[]=mysql_fetch_array($result1));

echo "<br>B <--<pre>";
print_r ($rows1);
echo "</pre><br><br>";
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$result3=array_diff_assoc($rows,$rows1);
echo "<br>Users that didnt send in their dayreport<pre>";
print_r ($result3);
echo "</pre><br><br>"
```

This is what I have till now. And this works till so far.

Hourimport 
id           int(11)    auto_increment
date         datetime
employee     int(11)
mail         int(11)
status       text

Comment: Please post attempted code and some data for a reproducible example. Your question description is great but needs actual illustration.

Comment: Do you have a `users` table as well? If so, please add it to the question. Also, what database are you using specifically? All relational databases use SQL - MySQL? SQL Server?

Comment: Can you show your create table syntax for your `hours` table? I need to know the `type` of your columns.

Comment: I added some code what I was trying, and I added the table columns like you asked @Gravy

Comment: Databaseclient mysqli      libmysql 5.5.47

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a table `users` with a primary key `id` column or something (and the `user` column is a number referencing `users.id`), and the `day` format is something that can be easily compared (for example `date`), you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(user) FROM hours WHERE day > :limit)
```

`:limit` is then a placeholder for the minimum day to filter against (I'm a Java guy and that's the syntax for JPA, for PHP I think it's `$1` but you'll figure it out ^^)

Comment: I will have a look into this. Thanks I will let you know the outcome.

Answer (score -2):

First, you need a table of all the users who submitted their hours. Then you need a table of ALL the users.

What you would then do, is do RIGHT OUTER JOIN on the two tables. The resultset would give you the users who haven't submitted their hours mapped to nulls.